# Pandas set column value based on matching row value and column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks likes this

```
   start        end            2017-06-08   2018-04-08  2019-04-20
   2018-04-20   2019-04-20      NaN           NaN          NaN
   2018-04-20   2019-04-20      NaN           NaN          NaN
   2017-06-08   2018-04-08      NaN           NaN          NaN
```

i need to make it like this

```
   start        end            2017-06-08  2018-04-20   2019-04-20
   2018-04-20   2019-04-20      NaN           1               1
   2018-04-20   2019-04-20      NaN           1               1
   2017-06-08   2018-04-08       1            1              NaN
```

This means that i will change the row value for matching column name.

Comment: I think your output is wrong.  Why did one column disappear?  In general, just drop to numpy and do broadcasted comparison. `(cols[:, None] <= end) & (cols[:, None] >= start)`

Comment: Can u show an example for how this can be done in numpy?

Answer (score 3):

> change the row value for matching column name

Here is my way if you want to match the column names from start and end columns:

```
m=(df.stack().reset_index(level=1)
 .set_index(0,append=True)['level_1'].unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool)*1)
df.update(m)
```

---

```
print(df)
        start         end  2017-06-08  2018-04-20  2018-04-08  2019-04-20
0  2018-04-20  2019-04-20         0.0         1.0         0.0         1.0
1  2018-04-20  2019-04-20         0.0         1.0         0.0         1.0
2  2017-06-08  2018-04-08         1.0         0.0         1.0         0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to `melt` first then compared , the `pivot` it back

```
s=df.reset_index().melt(['index','start','end'])
s['value']=s.variable.between(s.start,s.end).astype(int)
yourdf=s.pivot_table(index=['index','start','end'],columns='variable',values='value',aggfunc='first').reset_index(level=[1,2])
yourdf
variable       start         end  ...  2018-04-20  2019-04-20
index                             ...                        
0         2018-04-20  2019-04-20  ...           1           1
1         2018-04-20  2019-04-20  ...           1           1
2         2017-06-08  2018-04-08  ...           0           0
[3 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: I belive this will have som memory issues when working with a dataframe with over 200 000 rows

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
for col in df.columns[2:]:

    df[col] = np.where((df.start==col)|(df.end==col),1,np.nan)
```

Output:

```
0       start         end  2017-06-08  2018-04-20  2018-04-08  2019-04-20
1  2018-04-20  2019-04-20         NaN         1.0         NaN         1.0
2  2018-04-20  2019-04-20         NaN         1.0         NaN         1.0
3  2017-06-08  2018-04-08         1.0         NaN         1.0         NaN
```