# Iterate in column for specific value and insert 1 if found or 0 if not found in new column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as shown in the attached image. My columns of interest are **fgr** and **fgr1**. As you can see, they both contain values corresponding to years.

I want to iterate in the the two columns and for any value present, I want **1** if the value is present or else **0**.

For example, in **fgr** the first value is 2028. So, the first row in column 2028 will have a value 1 and all other columns have value 0.

I tried using *lookup* but I did not succeed. So, any pointers will be really helpful.

[Example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfxFd.png)

Data:
[Data file in Excel](https://filebin.net/a6agqgzpaygpt8es)

Comment: What happens for your non integer year?

Comment: @ALollz: Aim is to exclude the non-integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This fill do you job. You can use for loops aswell but I think this approach will be faster.

df["Matched"] = df["fgr"].isin(df["fgr1"])*1

Basically you check if values from one are in anoter column and if they are, you get True or False. You then multiply by 1 to get 1 and 0 instead of True or False.

Comment: @Nico_P: Unfortunately, it does not serve my purpose. For me, fgr and fgr1 are two separate columns that I need to consider. First, I want to check all values in fgr with the column names 2021-2036, and for any value present insert 1 or 0.

Then I repeat the same for values in fgr1. Hope I was clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307117/pandas-set-column-value-based-on-matching-row-value-and-column-name)

Not the most efficient, but should work for your case(*time consuming if large dataset*)

```
s = df.reset_index().melt(['index','fgr','fgr1'])
s['value'] = s.variable.eq(s.fgr.str[:4]).astype(int)
s['value2'] = s.variable.eq(s.fgr1.str[:4]).astype(int)
s['final'] = np.where(s['value']+s['value2'] > 0,1,0)
yourdf = s.pivot_table(index=['index','fgr','fgr1'],columns = 'variable',values='final',aggfunc='first').reset_index(level=[1,2])
yourdf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it gives me a null matrix. All 0 values apart from first 2 columns.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: I have added the link now.

Comment: Your column headers are not matching with row labels, for example: `2028` column headers will not match with `fgr` first row `2028.00` due to extra `.00` you need to have same values to match.

Comment: @maonjk: As I mentioned before, integer part of the number will be considered only. The Excel file attached shows it.

Comment: @Prax - Sorry, I can't access the excel file, but edited the answer, since your `fgr` and `fgr1` will always have year, I have considered first 4 digits of that, without converting the columns data type, hope this works!!!